# Failed to remove etcd after reset kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

When I try to `kubeadm reset -f`, it report the etcd server can not be removed, you must remove it manually.

```
failed to remove etcd member: error syncing endpoints with etc: etcdclient: no available endpoints. Please manually remove this etcd member using etcdctl
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this a control-plane (master) node?

If not: simply running `kubectl delete node <node_id>` should suffice (see reference below). This will update etcd and take care of the rest of cleanup. You'll still have to diagnose what caused the node to fail to reset in the first place if you're hoping to re-add it... but that's a separate problem. See discussion e.g., [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1300#issuecomment-548569829) on a related issue:

> If the node is hard failed and you cannot call kubeadm reset on it, it requires manual steps. you'd have to:
>
> 1. Remove the control-plane IP from the kubeadm-config CM ClusterStatus
> 2. Remove the etcd member using etcdctl
> 3. Delete the Node object using kubectl (if you don't want the Node around anymore)
>
> 1 and 2 apply only to control-plane nodes.

Hope this helps — if you *are* dealing with a master node, I'd be happy to include examples of what commands to run.

Comment: I have the same issue on a single node cluster (control-plane is a node), what should I do?